# How to keep the body (content) of website alligned with the center of background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to keep [my site](http://nickhumphries.com)'s content perfectly aligned with the center of its background image, is there a way to do this?

Currently my background is

```
body {
    background: url(http://nickhumphries.com/images/tucson-bgl3b2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-color: #fafafa;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%; 
    -moz-background-size: 100%; 
    -o-background-size: 100%; 
    background-size: 100%; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover; 
    text-align:center;
} 
#mainContainer {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Is there an issue?

Comment: When i open your site i see everything fine, all on the middle.

Comment: Looked good in the latest Chrome and IE, is there a particular browser where you're experiencing problems?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need text align center in your body since you are using divs over it.  and you should probably use #maincontainer as a class .maincontainer so you can reuse it seperately.

And why are you using 100% size and cover at the same time?  you can either resize it to cover or keep it at 100% right?

Play with these ideas.

Answer (score 0):

usually if i want to center something, i give it a fixed width and set margins left and right to auto